# Does OWB 11gR2 support Oracle Database 10g?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-warehouse-builder

I need to install OWB11gR2 as a stand alone instance in my local machine. Does OWB 11gR2 supports the database release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit? Can the mappings implemented in OWB 10.2.0.5 be used in 11gR2 release of OWB?

Comment: I have never tried but this page suggests that it is possible: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/warehouse/downloads/software/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will check it out...